# C# как определить габаритные размеры у фала 3DS?

Tags: c#, 3dsmax

имеется 3ds объект необходимо определить его габаритные размеры : высоту глубину ширину, подскажите в какую сторону копать

Comment: В какую вы копали до сих пор? Добавте код.

Comment: склоняюсь к тому что нужна dll которая работает с 3ds фалами, через неё получить габаритные размеры, вот какую dll взять понятия не имею, кода нет, потому что не знаю даже за что зацепиться